# can't communicate with rosmaster on other machine

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have two machines in the same local wifi network.
On the machine with the roscore I have set

```
- ROS_MASTER_URI: http://<own_ip>:11311
- ROS_IP: <own_ip>
- ROS_HOSTNAME: <own_ip> (I know I don't need this one, I just tested it. Also the machines hostname is just localhost.localdomain so I don't know if I can use thatvalue)
```

On the other machine I have set

```
- ROS_MASTER_URI: http://<ip_machine_with_master>:11311
- ROS_IP: <own_ip>
- ROS_HOSTNAME: <own_ip>
```

If I start a roscore and then try rostopic list on the other machine **I don't get the error "ERROR: unable to connect to Master!" but the terminal just shows empty space after the command.** If I run the command on the machine with the roscore I get displayed that /rosout and /rosout_agg are there.
Also I played a rosbag from the other machine which should publish a couple of topics but they also don't arrive at the master.

Could it be a problem that the machines are running different versions of ros? The master uses melodic and the other machine noetic.
Any ideas what could be going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377764/can%27t-communicate-with-rosmaster-on-other-machine/) by [SpaceTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/39589/spacetime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-05**:
First thing to check: firewall active on any of the involved machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to gvdhoorn I checked the firewall. As it is a device borrowed from work it has a very strict firewall indeed which should be my problem. I switchd to running everything on one machine in the end as I did not have the rights to change something about the firewall.e

---

Originally posted by [SpaceTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/39589/spacetime/) with karma: 50 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0